# MVC.net razor substring in view problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, razor

I am having a problem with razor and models.

In my view I have a model with a list with "article" objects.

So I do a foreach with `@MvcHtmlString.Create(article.Intro)` which works great.

Then when I want a substring of that intro:

`@MvcHtmlString.Create(article.Intro).ToHtmlString().Substring(0, 50)` the page ends in endless loop (which happens often when razor can't render something) without an error.

Does anyone know how I can get this substring ?

Comment: Why are you using _MvcHtmlString.Create_ (instead of just @article.Intro)? Is your _Intro_ field already HTML encoded? If not, you're causing an XSS vulnerability. If it is, then you can't just use _Substring_ because it might cut in the middle of entity like &amp;.

Comment: @article.intro is just plain nvarchar from db, I did the mvchtmlstring because I tought it might solve my substring problem, because I am not working directly on the property, but on the locally created htmlstring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply substring your article.Intro directly?

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(article.Intro.Substring(0, 50))
```

Comment: This can cause incorrect behavior. What if substring at position 49 starts a new table tag, then the output will be "...blablabla <tabl" since MvcHtmlString doesnt notice the whole tag

Comment: That problem exists either way; MvcHtmlString simply tells the view engine not to HtmlEncode the string value - aka "<span>" doesnt become "&lt;span&gt;".

Comment: This doesn't work either. I tried this first. Even when all my strings are greater then 20 en I do article.Intro.Substring(0, 2) The page gets in endless loop. I think it has more to do with th way razor binds the data. I already solved it another way but I want to know why this happens (It hppens often)

Comment: I think something else is going on here if a simple substring call is causing an endless loop. If you remove the substring, it renders fine?

Comment: Yes, then it works fine, when I do substring(0) also fine substring(more then 0,int) ... not fine

Comment: Odd. I'd suggest trying a test then; outside the context of a view (for example, a unit test), make a string and then invoke MvcHtmlString.Create() on it and see if it still causes the infinite loop. Also, what is the value of Article.Intro?

Comment: Also, just a hunch here, but is this coming directly from an ORM context like entity framework? You say above it's coming directly from the DB.

Comment: Value of article.intro is just a string. The object is a linq to sql class from a dbml.

Comment: Replace your variable article.Intro with a hard coded string and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: Sounds like your Linq to SQL class is the culprit then. Try this; get your object from Linq2Sql, then map it to another object. Then use that object on your view. It sounds like the db context is being called for the value when the view is rendering, causing the slowdown.

Comment: It is not a slowdown. On multiple occasions razor doesn't catch errors and does nothing, while your website apears te be loading infinitely

Answer (score 5):

`Substring(0, 50)` throws an *ArgumentOutOfRangeException* exception if any of your article intros is shorter than 50 characters. That's probably the cause of your strange problem.

Furthermore, the use of *MvcHtmlString* is incorrect since your data obviously isn't HTML encoded yet.

So a solution could be:

```
@article.Intro.Substring(0, Math.Min(article.Intro.Length, 50))
```

Comment: It is not an ArgumentOutOfRangeException error, all my strings are fine. The problem occurs often in razor. When razor has a problem while rendering it just doesnt return any header, not even the asp.net error page, so the page seems to keep rendering. The string is html.

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the fact that the properties in the model are linked to a datacontext and handled like dynamics. When razor executes its viewrendering, it cannot pass the dynamic properties to the function, and it crashed. But I am not sure